# Eclipse RCP- Property Page for folders only

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, plugin.xml

I am trying to create a property page using *plugin.xml*. I want this property page to appear only when you right click -> properties of folders only.

I used this code:

```xml
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
    <page
          class="my.properties.page.class"
          id="my.properties.page.id"
          name="My Properties Page">
          <enabledWhen>
              <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder"/>
          </enabledWhen>
   </page>
</extension>
```

This works when I open the properties from Navigator. But when opening it from Project Explorer, I can't see the properties page!

From Navigator:

[image]

From Project Explorer:

[image]

How can I make my properties page to be shown using Project explorer too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```xml
<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder" />
```

instead of `instanceof`.

Most objects in views are not actually instances of files and folders. Instead they are some UI object which can be 'adapted' to a file or folder, the `adapt` element deals with this.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot for the quick and helpful answer! Thanks for the clear explanation too.